# How to copy all Shapes from a Page in a VISIO file to another file

Tags: vba, visio

Purpose of this question

- How to select and copy all the figures from one page of one VISIO file (A.vsdx) to another page of another VISIO file (B.vsdx) at once

Implemented code

```
    Dim vsoApp As Visio.Application
    Dim vsoDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim new_vsoDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
    Dim vsoItemsCnt As Long
    Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape

           
    ' open the vsdx file (source)
    VISIOpath = "original.vsdx"
    Set vsoApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VISIOpath, visOpenRW)
    Set vsoDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(1)

    vsoItemsCnt = vsoApp.Documents.Count
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VSSXpath, visOpenRO)

    Set vsoApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(VISIOpath, visOpenRW)
    Set vsoDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(1)
    
    ' open the vsdx file (target)
    new_path = "new.vsdx"
    Call vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(new_path, visOpenRW)
    vsoItemsCnt = vsoApp.Documents.Count
    Dim new_vsoDoc As Visio.Document
    Set new_vsoDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Item(vsoItemsCnt)


    For Each vsoPage In vsoDoc.Pages
        vsoWindow.Page = vsoDoc.Pages.ItemU(vsoPage.NameU)

        If vsoPage.NameU = "foobar" Then
            For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
                
                vsoWindow.Selection.Select vsoShape, visSelect
                                            
            Next vsoShape
        
            vsoWindow.Selection.Copy
            newvsoDoc.Pages.Item(vsoPage.Name).Paste
            vsoWindow.Selection.DeSelectAll

        End If
    Next vsoPage
    
    newvsoDoc.SaveAs  "change_.vsdx"

    End Sub
```

There are two points of code that I do not know how to implement.

First.

- An alternative when ActiveWindow cannot be used in the command ActiveWindow.Select

Second.

- How to copy all Shapes while preserving the X and Y coordinates for the Page

Requirements

- Copying while keeping the connector connected

Comment: Hope you can find many hints at [thread in Russian Visio forum](https://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1049), for protect connectors positions use group all shapes before copy

Comment: [Super Utilities and Tools for MS Visio](https://paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities/) by [Paul Herber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6405357/paul-herber) can **Copy page to another document**

Answer (score 0):

1. "when ActiveWindow cannot be used" - I don't know about the "cannot", but when the active window is another then the one you need, you can set it by:

   Application.Windows.ItemEx("original.vsdx").Activate

Better use a variable though.

2. copy all Shapes while preserving the X and Y coordinates:

Draw a rectangle in the left bottom corner of the page - used for positioning the group.

```
ActivePage.DrawRectangle(0,0,1,1)
```

Group everything

```
  ActiveWindow.SelectAll
  grp = ActiveWindow.Selection.Group
```

Set PinX and PinY to bottom left

```
  grp.Cells("PinX").Formula = 0
  grp.Cells("PinY").Formula = 0
```

Now copy, paste to the new document and position the group at 0,0.

Cleaning:

- Ungroup the newly inserted shape - you will have stored its instance in a variable, or you go with the last shape on the page.
- Delete the helper rectangle. Either you gave it a name (eg "helper_shape"), or you go for the last shape on the page (activepage.shapes(activepage.shapes.count)).

3. Copying while keeping the connector connected

If you copy by using the am method, the connectors will stay connected.