# How to copy objects from a VISIO file to the same location in another file

Tags: vba, visio

I created a VBA program to copy from one VISIO file (A.vsdx) to another VISIO file (B.vsdx) using the Selection.Copy method.

I want to copy it to the same location as the A.vsdx file, but it doesn't work. It was
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.paste
Looking at this page, visCopyPasteNoTranslate seems to be good, but it didn't work as expected.

Alternatively, I considered using the Selection.Top method, but it didn't work because VISIO's Selection doesn't have a Top or Left method.

The pseudo code is shown below.

```
    Dim group_ As visio.Shape

    For Each vsoPage In vsoDoc.Pages
        vsoWindow_old.Page = vsoDoc.Pages.ItemU(vsoPage.NameU)
        vsoWindow_new.Page = newvsoDoc.Pages.ItemU(vsoPage.NameU)
                
        For Each vsoShape In vsoPage.Shapes
            vsoWindow_old.Selection.Select vsoShape, visSelect
        Next vsoShape
        
        If Not (vsoWindow_old.Selection Is Nothing) Then
            ''' This code doesn't work
            Set group_ = vsoWindow_old.Selection.group
            '''
            vsoWindow_old.Selection.Copy
            
            newvsoDoc.Pages.Item(vsoPage.Name).Paste visCopyPasteNoTranslate
            
        End If
        
        vsoWindow_old.Selection.DeselectAll
    
    Next vsoPage
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestions from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022162/how-to-copy-all-shapes-from-a-page-in-a-visio-file-to-another-file)?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't responded to your suggestion.
Do you mean Paul Herber's software?

It's difficult to use software that isn't approved by my company, so I'm looking for other options.

Comment: No, I mean [Russian tread](https://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1050).

Comment: I tried to read Russian with google translate, but I couldn't understand. Sorry.

Comment: My example is highly simplified, in the Russian forum we tried to copy shapes belonging to locked layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method [PasteToLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.pastetolocation), but you must know X,Y-coordinates for paste!

I wrote the code hastily, for a simplified case:

- both documents contain only single page
- the target document has a blank page (no shapes)
- target page have not locked layers [updated]

  ```
  Sub For_user18616709()
  Dim s_d As Document ' source document
  Dim t_d As Document ' target document
  Dim s_p As Page ' source document
  Dim t_p As Page ' target document
  Dim gr As Shape ' temprery shape for copy
  Dim sl As Selection ' Selection
  Dim shs As Shape ' temprery shape after paste
  Dim xp As Double, yp As Double ' X, Y coordinates
  Set s_d = ActiveDocument ' define source doc
  Set s_p = s_d.Pages(1) ' define source page
  Set t_d = Documents(2) ' define target doc
  ActiveWindow.SelectAll ' Select all shapes at source page
  Set sl = ActiveWindow.Selection ' define sl
  Set gr = sl.Group ' define temprery shape for copy
  xp = gr.Cells("PinX") ' define X-coordinate of temprery shape
  yp = gr.Cells("PinY") ' define Y-coordinate of temprery shape
  gr.Copy ' copy to clipboard temprery shape for copy
  gr.Ungroup ' destroy temprery shape for copy
  Set t_p = t_d.Pages(1) ' define target page
  t_p.PasteToLocation xp, yp, 0 ' paste to target page with location
  Set shs = t_p.Shapes(1) ' define temprery shape after paste
  shs.Ungroup ' destroy temprery shape after paste
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I tried using cells ("PinX"), but I couldn't program because I couldn't use Selection.cells ("PinX").

Thank you for telling me how to get PinX by using Selection.Group.
I was also unaware of a method called PasteToLocation. I will use it in my program. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried two measures based on the answers I received, but neither of them worked. The code was added to the question text
As a premise, my visio file has grouped shapes joined by a connector. It is necessary to copy the join information between shapes as well.
"First measure"
set gl = sl.group and
The code of xp = gr.cells ("PinX") did not work with an error.
"Second measure"
The method of looping each shape with a for statement and copying each worked well, and I was able to keep the XY coordinates and copy. However, the connection information between shapes will be lost.

Comment: What you mean as *connection information* ?

Comment: I mean the glued shapes.

Comment: Ignore glued shapes (connection information) as they are not the main issue. The biggest problem is that "visio.window.Selection.Group" doesn't work.
"ActiveWindow.Selection.Group" worked.

Comment: Error '2032465766(86db089a')

Comment: It may be because you are operating Visio from Excel VBA for various reasons. I will investigate a little more.

Comment: Why you dont want use ```ActiveWindow.SelectAll```  and iterate all shapes ?